# If mag.field and Ele.field are same,what is the need of studying both?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, inertial-frames

We learnt magnetic field is electric field but viewed from a different frame of reference. Then why do we need to worry about B. We could very well take a frame where it is E?

Answer (score 2):

> We learnt magnetic field is electric field but viewed from a different
>   frame of reference.

This isn't true. If it were true, there would be no propagating electromagnetic waves (light).

It *is* true that a purely electric field in some (inertial) frame of reference (IFR) has a magnetic component in other, relatively moving IFRs.

But, in general, one can't find an IFR where the electromagnetic field is purely electric.

---

If you study [electromagnetism in covariant form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism), you'll see that what we consider two distinct but not independent vector fields, $\vec E$ and $\vec B$, are in fact 'combined' into an [anti-symmetric tensor field of rank 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) that contains the components of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ (appropriately scaled to have the same units).

Answer (score 1):

To make the magnetic field zero even just instantaneously you would have to use a frame of reference in which all charges in the problem are instantaneously stationary. This is not usually possible. Even when it is possible (e.g. in a problem where all charges are moving with the same velocity) it is often not a convenient frame of reference to work in.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just casually say electric field and magnetic field are the same. They are the same with respect to change of frame of reference having constant velocity or rest. You can interchange or replace E and B in equations of moving electromagnetic field.

Electric and magnetic fields are the same when n (number density) or velocity or both are very high.
In engineering work or our daily life, you can't consider them as same.

(although I have used word 'same') it is not the right word, basically, they are the part of one thing that is an electromagnetic field.

Every part of the theory has its importance in its domain. our life and society are mostly based on classical phenomena It has evolved on that basis.

It's wrong to say that "why to study it when it's the same".
Repeating' every theory has its own domain.'
You can't say I can get classical mechanics from relativity and quantum mechanics then, why to study classical. 
Classical has its own domain and quantum has its other. It's like the evolution of theory, where you always increase the circumference of the circle(knowledge).

you can get general relativity from string theory then go and just study string theory.you will understand nothing.

You should increase your circumference step by step. One can't say I will make a circle of infinite radius and go till its end. You will never understand its significance .you can't just do that.
You understood them the same phenomenon because you were knowing them to be different. And that is the beauty. The pleasure of finding things out. One can't see the beauty of the world sitting on light.

Comment: What is the number of density you are telling ?